# within MVC3 or MVC 4 based webwiste post is not working altogether if I move its virtual location to sub folder

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have developed a website and published it on server http://www.exampledummywebsite.com and in post I have url something like `/Home/GetResult`, where `Home` is controller and `GetResult` is Action Method on Controller.

It's working fine so far, no problem with development and deployment.

Now I would like to move complete website to some sub folder and would like to access this by followoing url; Now on server side it's all complete move to a folder and map that folder with virtual sub folder.

http://www.exampledummywebsite.com/Version1

Now my problems get begin, it's all post in website is not able to do their job. Then I had try it with one of the post by changing

From Post URL : `/Home/GetResult` to `/Version1/Home/GetResult`.

It start working, but why so, if this is the only way then it means it would require change in post url every time when we move it to some sub virtal folder.

Java Script before creating a sub Virtual Directory:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "/Home/GetResult",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    success: function (returnPayload) {
        if (returnPayload == "true") {
            // do job for success on UI.
        }
        else {
            // do job for Failuer on UI.
        }

    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        // do job for Exception on UI.
    },
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    processData: false,
    async: false
});
```

Java Script After creating a sub Virtual Directory:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "/Version1/Home/GetResult",

    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    success: function (returnPayload) {
        if (returnPayload == "true") {
            // do job for success on UI.
        }
        else {
            // do job for Failuer on UI.
        }

    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        // do job for Exception on UI.
    },
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    processData: false,
    async: false
});
```

Above is the simple snippet includes post before/after creating a virtual directory.
and in the above code I am unable to post if I don't change the post url.

Comment: It wouldn't be the case, could you please show us the calling code?

Comment: The problem is with your code. Always, take the help of html helpers to generate the url for you such as `@Url.Action`, `@Html.ActionLink` instead of hard-coding. It will generate the proper url irrespective of your virtual-directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hard-coded url is creating problems for you. Take help of html helpers instead. Ex:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '@Url.Action("GetResult", "Home")', // Will generate the proper url for you.
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    success: function (returnPayload) {
    }
});
```

As pointed by [Erik The Viking](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61164/erik-the-viking) on comments, the razor syntax works only if your script is within the page and won't work with external javascript file. If you are using external file, then I recommend you to assign the urls to a variable accessible to the external script. Ex:

**index.cshtml**

```
<script src="~/Scripts/MyAppScript.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    MyApp.GetResultUrl = '@Url.Action("GetResult", "Home")';
</script>
```

**MyAppScript.js**

```
var MyApp = {};

// Somewhere on the file....
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: MyApp.GetResultUrl,
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        success: function (returnPayload) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: That only works if your javascript is in your razor view.  If it's an external .js file, it won't work.

Comment: As a comment on this, if you have a separate javascript library, you of course couldn't do this. What we typically do is we'll pass in a variable to our library in an 'Init' like method that represents the path using @Url.Action

Comment: it's resolved by using @Url.Action("GetResult","Home"),

yes it is a good practice to keep JS in separate file. i made it and declare a variable on top of the file and in separate file.